# Inject constant to a Controller in angular js(Issue with modal popup)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-modal

I am showing a modal popup on click of a button in a row in ng grid.So to get a form in the modal popup i am filling it with JSON Schema as follows

The Html Of Modal Pop Up is

```
<div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Row</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="form" sf-model="entity"></form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$close()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The schema is put into the constant like below in an external js file:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngGrid','ui.bootstrap']);
app.constant('UserPopUpSchema', {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        FullName: { type: 'string', title: 'FullName' },
        UserName: { type: 'string', title: 'UserName' },
        Password: { type: 'string', title: 'Password' },
        EmailAddress: { type: 'string', title: 'EmailId' },
        Phone: {type:'string',title:'phNum'}
    }
});
```

So on click of a row in `ng-grid` I am executing a function called edit row ,which would open the pop up and fill the form according to the constant.

```
 $scope.editRow = function (grid,row) {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'PopUpTemplate.htm',
            controller:['$modalInstance', 'grid', 'row','UserPopUpSchema', function($modalInstance,grid,row){

        schema = 'UserPopUpSchema';

         entity = angular.copy(row.entity);
         form = [
           'FullName',
           'UserName',
           'Password',
           'EmailId',
          'phNum'
           ];


            }],
            resolve: {
                grid: function () { return grid; },
                row: function () { return row; }
            }
        });
    };
```

But here I am a bit confused on how to inject a constant to a controller function .As a result the modal appear with a blank form.

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: resolve: {
                UserPopUpSchema: function () { return UserPopUpSchema; }
            }

Comment: @Niyaz.Sorry, I didn't get your suggestion.

Comment: Injecting Constant is same as like injecting other dependencies , ControllerName.$inject = ['UserPopUpSchema'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'PopUpTemplate.htm',
    controller: function ($modalInstance, grid, row, UserPopUpSchema) {
     // Do Stuff
    },
    resolve: {
        grid: function () {
            return grid;
        },
        row: function () {
            return row;
        },
        UserPopUpSchema: function () {
            return UserPopUpSchema;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this is what i mentioned in the comment

Comment: @Niyaz We think alike ;)

Comment: Yup Now I am able to inject constant into controller but Not able to fill the form schema in modal

Comment: Fine.Thank You that saved me a couple of hours

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.controller('Myctrl',function($scope,UserPopUpSchema) {
    $scope.editRow = function (grid,row) {
        $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'PopUpTemplate.htm',
        controller:['$modalInstance', 'grid', 'row','UserPopUpSchema', function($modalInstance,grid,row){

    schema = 'UserPopUpSchema';

     entity = angular.copy(row.entity);
     form = [
       'FullName',
       'UserName',
       'Password',
       'EmailId',
      'phNum'
       ];


        }],
        resolve: {
            grid: function () { return grid; },
            row: function () { return row; }
            UserPopUpSchema: function () { return UserPopUpSchema; }
        }
    });
};
 });

 and in the modal instance controller inject the UserPopUpSchema along with grid and row
```

Answer (score 0):

$modal.open() accept a "resolve" property in which you can pass all the data you want.

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'templateUrl',
    controller: 'controllerName',
    resolve: {
        data: function(){
            // Here, return a JSON object containing all the data you want to pass to the controller.  
        }
    }
});
```

Then your controller will look like this :

```
yourApp.controller('controllerName', function ( $scope, $modalInstance, data ){
    // Here, using data, you can access the JSON object you passed previously.
});
```